# Default client printer permissions on 2003 terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, printing, windows-terminal-services

Is it possible to change default permissions of printers that are created on terminal server sessions by clients? We have a terminal server that is shared between our head and branch offices and sometimes there is a need to print something from HO to the BO's printers. Now I have to assign the permissions manually, and those are gone as soon as the client disconnects.

I know I can set up VPN and install those printers on the TS as local ones, but this is my plan B :)

Comment: Are you saying you cannot use printer redirection?  What do you mean by "I have to assign permissions manually"?

Comment: I can use printer redirection fine, the use case here: Tom and Sally are connected to the same terminal server. Tom wants to print something on Sally's redirected printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Termina server (rdp server now) work like that  :

-user connected on server view printer localy installed on the server or connected by script/group policy.
-if remote printer is enabled on tse and client tse , user on the server can view localy installed printer on the server if the driver is installed on the server (for 2003 server). And only the user connecting their printer .
To resolve your share problem with connected printer via remote session its  better to use printer as local one (with ip with or without vpn) because rdp 2003 is not very good at handling printer job. And this prevent share right delete.
And there is near 0 compression on print job with old rdp protocole.

2008 and later are better at handling printer job inside rdp session.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be my only option. One more thing: the clients connect to the RDP Server through Internet from behind NAT. I cannot set up the printers using client's public IP's and expect them to work, I need to set up VPN and install the printers using local addresses, right?

Comment: You can use lpd open port if you have fixed ip on client but this is ugly and not very secure and not ok with all printer. And you need fixed ip on client or play with dynamic dns tools . With all the problems with this setup...  Or use a vpn , setup , and its done :)